# Fragment lifecycle with respect to it's activity

Tags: android, fragment, android-lifecycle

**Situation**
My activity waits on an Async operation and after it hears back from async operation, it needs to pass information to 2 fragments inside it.

**Requirement**
1. Both fragments need their `onCreateView` calls to be done for them to have their layouts loaded, 
2. They need for themselves to be attached to their activity so that `getActivity()` works.

I wrote a `setData()` method in both the fragments and am looking for the "correct" place in the activity's lifecycle to invoke them.

`onCreate()` of the activity does not work, `onStart()` of the activity does not work and `onStart()` of the fragment does not work.

Nothing works, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The official documentation for [the Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle) explains this clearly - please refer to it and then ask follow-up questions if something is unclear.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that one out.

Comment: I have Activity1--->Fragment1--->(Nested)fragment2<===>Activity2  when I'm on Activity2 when I press the back button fragment2(Activity1) at that time I need to know which method is fired in fragment2? I just want to refresh fragment2 content when user click back button on Activity2!

Comment: @LOG_TAG: "onResume" will be fired.

Answer (score 16):

This Image will be helpful to understand both life cycles together.

As many people complaints and it is somewhat valid argument that this life cycle is too complicated, in Google I/O 2018,They have suggested to use Architecture component Framework. Please check this [Docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/)

[image]

Comment: why, Google, just why? This is why nobody likes fragments :D

Answer (score 0):

when you are at `Activity2---->backpress--->Fragment2(Activity1)`---means `Activity1` again attach from `fragment2` so on `OnAactivityCreated()` method `Activity1` is completely loaded ....so at that we can call `setData()` method of your Activity1...

Answer (score 0):

onAttachFragment()-activity is called before onCreate()-activity and after onAttach()-fragment

Answer (score -1):

Call onDestroy on onStop of your fragment.  This should call onCreate when the fragment is launched. 
Let me know if works as an ideal solution for your problem.

Comment: onDestroy and onStop should not be called. They are callback functions in the lifecycle of Activities and Fragments.